# Make child tab overflow tab bar (using flexbox)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a little design flourish to some tabs.

The tabs are contained inside a tab bar, which has a bottom border.

When a tab is active I want it to appear as if it's on the same level of the content, with the other tabs appearing set back.

To do this, I need to make the section of border beneath the active tab disappear - my first thought was to set the tab background white and overlap the parent - but this doesn't work.

Anyone got any ideas as to how to get the effect I'm looking for?

```css
.container {
  padding: 30px;
}

.tab-bar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0, .12);
    height: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 48px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

.tab[data-state="active"] {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-bar">
    <div class="tab" data-state="active">Active</div>
    <div class="tab">Not Active</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Link to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy7trjc9/)

Comment: where is the content?

Comment: draw the bottom border from the non active tabs, add eventually a pseudo element to fill the room left. overflow:hidden on the parent hides shadows and also do not allow children to stand on top of the border in order to hide it . example : https://jsfiddle.net/3v7xm650/

Comment: @G-Cyr - you have a working answer but haven't promoted it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **from earlier comment**
>
> draw the bottom border from the non active tabs
>
> add eventually a pseudo element to fill the room left.
>
> `overflow:hidden` on the parent hides shadows and also do not allow children to stand on top of the border in order to hide it

What you could do :

```css
.container {
  padding: 30px;
}

.tab-bar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 48px;
}

.tab {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.tab-bar::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.tab[data-state="active"] {
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 -4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  color: red;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-bar">
    <div class="tab" data-state="active">Active</div>
    <div class="tab">Not Active</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `overflow: hidden` from `.tab-bar`.

But after you remove it. It seems not to be as you wanted ("the same level of the content").

So I edited `box-shadow` of active tab. to make it with no `box-shadow`from button.

`border-bottom: 1px solid white` is responsible to override `tab-bar` border

See Full Example here:

```css
.container {
  padding: 30px;
}

.tab-bar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0, .12);
    height: 48px;
}
.tab {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 48px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

.tab[data-state="active"] {
  box-shadow: -4px -2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 4px -2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-bar">
    <div class="tab" data-state="active">Active</div>
    <div class="tab">Not Active</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kareem, but it's not what I'm looking for. The whole thing (tabs and content) is already contained within a border, so the only shadow I want to see is the left/right side (depending on which tab is active).

Comment: is the problem only with upper shadow? if yes i'll edit it to match what you're looking for

Comment: In the example, only the right hand shadow should show - this can be fixed by reinstating overflow: hidden on the tab-bar.